# Phonetic Substitution Cipher

Tags: cipher

This cipher uses a unique phonetic alphabet.

**Consonant sounds** (not necessarily in the text):

m b p f v r
l d t s z y
n j ch sh zh* w
ng g k thin** this** h

*Zh refers to the s in conclusion or the j in bonjour

**Thin and This refer to the th in those words

**Vowel sounds** (not necessarily in the text):

bat bit but baa bot 
bet beat boot book

I haven't seen anyone else do something like this so I thought it would make a good challenge for those of you who are accustomed to breaking normal substitution ciphers.

For rhotic vowels, I just used Rs.

You can assume I did not choose the correct vowel sounds. However, the second puzzle piece should allow you to break it regardless.

**Transcription:** ab cd efgbi ajkl. ab mbnkfom pqo qr ecrcrg as oqt ufr vqoeqg avcjg wg. wg gaorm cjg gj vb fb xbrbat abmbya uaj, cz ecrcrg n*mwrg hb, ab dbr hfb, &wz tgcrmbi $odb taj kqi.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you distinguish /ə/ (**a**go, mem**o**ry), and /ʌ/ (b**u**t)? What about the /oʊ/ vowel sound, as in "boat" - is that a potential sound?

Comment: (Also, is there any chance we could get a transcription of this, with a random letter replacing each symbol?)

Comment: 1. Yes those are separate sounds. For the most part, I try to spell words as if they were articulated as clearly as possible, which means avoiding the /ə/ (schwa) since for the most part it is what sounds get reduced to when they are said fast and unstressed. There are some exceptions to this because sometimes the schwa sound is the full sound, such as with "book" and "look". The only time I used the sound is with the ou in the word "couldn't" but I should also have used it in the word "turned".

Comment: 2. The oa in "boat" is actually the u in "but" + the oo in "boot". They are shown here as two separate sounds.

Comment: 3. I unfortunately don't have time to do that today but I can help by revealing that the half size letters are vowel sounds and the tall letters are consonant sounds. Hopefully this makes it a more reasonable challenge.

Comment: I had already guessed that the half-size letters were vowels - that part was perfectly reasonable to figure out based on their positions within words. I wasn't sure how diphthongs were treated though, which is why I asked. (Clarification that they were split is helpful, since I'm not entirely familiar with RP or other British English accents (being an American speaker myself)). Your first response surprises me though -- /ʊ/ is the same as /ə/? I wasn't aware that happened in *any* accent. They're pretty distinct for me.

Comment: Yes this is the trouble with accents. I have just looked it up and it is a feature of many accents that /ʊ/ is often unrounded to /ɘ/. There are clearly words I think of as using the same sound that don't "officially". I suspect this needs to be approached like Ancient Hebrew where there are no written vowel sounds - just ignore them when you are unsure. Edit: oh sorry that is a different sound so yeah ignore the vowels or just ignore this challenge that I am clearly not knowledgeable enough to create.

Comment: Actually if I present the challenge in the format that I originally showed it at my club my choice of vowel sounds is less fatal... I'll do that.

Comment: I have painstakingly transcribed it but I am very nervous I made a mistake. Some else should probably check it at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code, translating symbols to their [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) equivalents:

> Black is the transcription letter, blue is the IPA symbol for the sound.
>   [image]
>
>  Two-unit shapes are consonants, and one-unit-tall shapes are vowels. Mirroring a consonant across a vertical axis changes a sound from voiced to unvoiced or vice versa; the sounds that don't have counterparts get symmetric symbols. The fricative/sibilant-ish sounds have the "heavy" part on top and some roughly corresponding stop-ish sounds have the heavy part on the bottom. There's no pattern in which direction is voiced, or which asymmetric symbols get paired with symmetric ones, though.

The message is:

> /ʌi æm gɛtiŋ ʌuld. ʌi diklɛrd wɔr ɔn gænænt ʌv rɔs ðɛn fɔrgɔt ʌbæut ɪt. ɪt tʌrnd æut tu bi ɛi ʤiniʌs ʌidijʌ ðʌu, æz gænænt kʊdɪnt wi, ʌi min wɛi hɪz stændiŋ armi sʌu lɔŋ./
>
>  "I am getting old. I declared war on Ganant of Ross, then forgot about it. It turned out to be a genius idea though, as Ganant couldn't <s>pee</s>, I mean pay his standing army so long."

How I figured it out:

> The most likely way to start a sentence with a single word with two vowel sounds is "I". (I had transcribed this as /ai/ at first.) The most natural short word to follow that is "am", and then after that something ending in "-ing". Once that was done, "genius idea" stood out to me for `/?i?ia? ai?i?a/`, and at that point I could always find a word with only one blank to fill in.

Comment: It is ridiculous how good you are at these! I will accept as correct since you basically have it, but it was "pay" not "weigh". "pee, I mean pay" was actually a mistake I made while writing it and decided it worked to leave it in as a mistake the actual writer was correcting. You are correct about the name, Ganant, and Roos is the county Ross.

Comment: On reflection I believe the mistake I have been making is with the /ə/ sound and assuming it is just the /ʊ/ sound. In other words I think I have the correct understanding of /ʊ/ and the wrong understanding of /ə/. Otherwise I haven't done too badly... you can probably tell that I haven't studied phonetics. This alphabet is based on a phonetic fantasy language I made but all the phonetics are the result of me just trying to make sense of the sounds and find patterns between them. There is no "symmetry/asymmetry/direction" pattern because I just hadn't discovered that.

Comment: @JoshuaBizley Even if you aren't experienced with phonetics, there are still a lot of patterns here! Reminds me a bit of [Canadian syllabics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Aboriginal_syllabics). (And for what it's worth, I also have trouble with /ə/ -- in my accent, it's essentially the same as /ʌ/. And I also have the cot-caught merger, which doesn't help things.)